# Extra + signs on my program

Tags: java

I wrote a program for my Computer Science class where it reads a file and imports the data and then just adds the numbers but it seems to be adding an extra addition sign.

```
import java.io.*; //necessary for File and IOException 
import java.util.*; //necessary for Scanner
public class Tester
{
public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
   {
    Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("/Volumes/DVLUP Flash/Numbers.txt"));

    int maxIndx = -1; //-1 so when we increment below, the first index is 0
    String text[] = new String[1000]; //To be safe, declare more than we
        while(sf.hasNext( ))
        {
            maxIndx++;
            text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine( ); 
            //System.out.println(text[maxIndx]); //Remove rem for testing
        }
        sf.close();

        for(int j =0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(text[j]);
        }
        String answer = ""; //We will accumulate the answer string here. 
        int sum; //accumulates sum of integers
        for(int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(text[j]);
            sum = 0;
            answer = ""; 
            while(sc.hasNext())
            {
                int i = sc.nextInt();
                answer = answer + i + " + ";
                sum = sum + i; 
            }
            //sc.next();
            answer = answer + " = " + sum; 
            System.out.println(answer);
        } 
    }
}
```

The output is

```
12 + 10 + 3 + 5 +  = 30
18 + 1 + 5 + 92 + 6 + 8 +  = 130
2 + 9 + 3 + 22 + 4 + 11 + 7 +  = 58
```

There's an extra after the last number, how do I fix that?

Comment: Note that you're mixing up pairs of `Scanner` methods: if you're going to call `sf.nextLine()`, check there is a next line with `sf.hasNextLine()`, not `sf.hasNext()`; similarly call `hasNextInt()` before calling `nextInt()`, not `hasNext()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the last iteration you are having an "extra" plus sign because that´s the way you are printing it. You are ending the `String` with a `+` as it can be seen in your while loop.

to change it either add the `+` before the value as

```
if(sc.hasNext()) {
   int i = sc.nextInt();
   answer = i + "";
   sum += i;
   while(sc.hasNext())
      {
          i = sc.nextInt();
          answer = answer + " + " + i;
          sum = sum + i; 
      }
}
```

Or if you use Java 8 you could use the `StringJoiner` as

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" + ");
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    i = sc.nextInt();
    // This automaticly includes a " + " between the values.
    joiner.add(String.valueOf(i));
    sum = sum + i; 
}
```

Comment: The OP can even replace the input array with a Collection and use a Stream + Joiner. -> No evil while loop.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            answer = answer + i + " + ";
            sum = sum + i; 
        }
```

put

```
answer = answer.substring(0, answer.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to conditionally prepend a plus sign *before* appending each number in any case *other* than the first number:

```
answer = ""; 
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    if (answer.length() > 0) {
        answer += " + ";
    }
    answer = answer + i;
    sum = sum + i; 
}
```